# How to disable PuTTY to not sending CR at the end of the buffer?

Tags: putty, serial-port, buffer, carriage-return

When I send something through PuTTY serial port I receive what I've wrote and an extra character, including a CR. Is a problem because it hasn't happened until now that I've started to use this program, not before. I'm sure it has something to do with the configuration but I don't know what.

I'm working with a serial port from a PIC, I've been doing all the job with Termite 3.4 but from now on I'm trying with PuTTY. If I send something through Termite I recieive what is expected, however it doesen't happen with PuTTY.

```
#For example sending 'ID' with:
__Termite__ The buffer reads --> 'I', 'D', '\n', '\0', '\0', '\0'

__PuTTY__ The buffer reads --> 'I', 'D', '\0', '\0', '\r', 'E'

#For example sending 'DB' with:
__Termite__ The buffer reads --> 'D', 'B', '\n', '\0', '\0', '\0'

__PuTTY__ The buffer reads --> 'D', 'B', '\0', '\0', '\r', 'C'

#For example sending 'CA' with:
__Termite__ The buffer reads --> 'C', 'A', '\n', '\0', '\0', '\0'

__PuTTY__ The buffer reads --> 'C', 'A', '\0', '\0', '\r', 'L'
```

The current PuTTY configuration is:

- Auto wrap mode initally on
- Use background colour to erase screen
- Answerback to ^E = PuTTY
- Local Echo = Force On
- Line Edit = Force On
- The Backspace key = Control-? (127)
- The Home and End key = Standard
- The Function keys and keypad = ESC[n~
- Initial state of cursor keys= Normal
- Initial state of numeric keypad = Normal
- Control-Alt is different from AltGr
- Response to remote title query (SECURITY) = Empty string
- Serial COM8
- 115200 bauderate
- 8 data bits
- 1 stop bits
- None Parity
- None Flow control

Please I'll appreciate all help, I need to know how I do to make the final CR not to appear.

Comment: Well, I know I've suggested the move of your question myself. But as there's actually the [same question already](https://superuser.com/q/1236513/213663), it was not really appropriate.

Comment: Should I delete this one too? It might help someone to redirect to the post we're talking about so

Comment: OK, so accept that it is duplicate, this way your wording of the problem will redirect to the existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is that PuTTY always sends CR/LF when Line Editnig is On, LF can be not showed but CR. So finally I had to edit my code doing a mask to prevent seeing CR.

This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1236513/prevent-sending-of-cr-lf-in-putty) explains it better. This current post is a repost from Stack Overflow of a deleted post for off-topic reasons.